# I'm not able to get a Expo Push Notifications Token

Tags: expo

I'm stuck in the notification sections. When i load the app on real device, using expo go, i get this error:

```
 Error encountered while fetching Expo token, expected an OK response, received: 400 (body: "{"errors":[{"code":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"The Expo push notification service is supported only for Expo projects Ensure you are logged in to your Expo developer account on the computer from which you are loading your project.","isTransient":false}]}").
```

I don't have an account on the *Expo.dev* site. Is this the problem?
The version of expo I'm using is `sdk47`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by logging into my expo account from the terminal in Visual Studio Code where I have project open.

You need an expo account. You can create one for free.

Then in the terminal you have to type:

`expo login`

It then will ask you for your Username/email address and then your password for the expo account.

When you type those in it should log you in and you should be able to get your push token.

This is what it should look like in the Terminal:

[image]